# Square matrix with independent columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So my question is can we conclude that a square matrix with independent columns would be a basis for $$R^{n=m}$$ right? no matter what right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is not a basis.

A square matrix $A$ with $n$ column/row entries whose columns, as column vectors, form a linearly independent set satisfies $\text{Col}(A) = \mathbb R^n$. Meaning the set of column vectors which make up the columns of the matrix form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$, as there are exactly $n$ of them.

Comment: But there are matrices that doesn't have orthogonal columns, but the columns are independent. Isn't orthogonality is a requirement for the formation of a space?

Comment: No. For example $(1,1)^T$ and $(1,2)^T$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^2$